# x-editable access attribute value of trigger element

Tags: jquery-plugins, inline-editing, x-editable

I am using [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) for in-line editing inside my web app. I would like to pass additional parameters to server, which I would like to read from data- attributes on trigger element. Here is my editable element:

```
<a href="#" data-url="save_url" data-pk="271" data-type="text" data-value="Value" class="editable" data-param="XXX">Value</a>
```

I would like to pass data-param attribute, but I don't know how to access trigger element. I tried via `$(this).data('param')`, but I get null... My full editable code:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('.editable').editable({
    params: { param: $(this).data('param') }
});
```

Calling `$('.editable').data('param')` doesn't come into account since I have many `.editable` elements present.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm answering in case somebody needs to know:

```
$('.editable').editable({
    params: function(params) {
        // add additional params from data-attributes of trigger element
        params.param1 = $(this).editable().data('param');
        params.param2 = $(this).editable().data('nextparam');
        return params;
    }
)
```

Comment: thousand thanks!
This should be added to that XEditable library's doc too!

Comment: When I try use this in the value parameter of editable() it errors 'undefined is not a function'

Comment: @stef you will have to share your code in order to help you